# Print without linefeed in R

Tags: r, printing

How can i print wihtout linefeed  in  R?

```
> for (i in 1:3)
 +   print(i)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
```

what i want to get is :1 2 3,i can do it  with cat

```
> for( i in 1:3)
+   cat(i," ")
1  2  3  >
```

How can i do that with print ?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do this? For example, does `cat` not handle the data type you want to print?

Answer (score 2):

If you must do it with `print`, you can create an `integer` method for `print`

```
> print.integer <- function(x, ...) cat(x, " ") 
> for(i in 1:3) print(i)
1 2 3 >
```

Answer (score 1):

because you are using  `print`, and that is how print will work for an atomic vector. (the behaiviour of `print.default`)

Your options are to use `cat` (as in your example) or to  use `message` with `appendLF == FALSE` (Thanks to @GSee for the `appendLF = FALSE`)

```
for( i in 1:3)message(i, appendLF = FALSE)
```

As GSee states, if you insist on using `print`, then you need to define a print method for your data.type (which will call `cat` or `message` or similar in the background)

Comment: `?cat` indicates that no `linefeed` would mean "123" on the same line, not on different lines.  But, you're close with `message` -- `for(i in 1:3) message(i, appendLF=FALSE)`

Comment: Oops. Misunderstood the question (I thought the OP did not want the `[1], [2] etc`. Thanks for the heads up